Referencing overriden by list of figures
I have an issue with my report reference numbering. My List of Figures numbering seems to have overwritten my document reference numbering.
The references in my list of figures start at 1, which means the references in my main body starts at [2].
However, I want the reference in my main body to start at 1, how do I fix this please?
\documentclass[conf]{new-aiaa}
%\documentclass[journal]{new-aiaa} for journal papers
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\section{Introduction}


\lettrine{T}{his} project \cite{burton1992propellers}. 

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pictures/Three-point-bending-test.jpg} 
    \caption{Three-point bend test to determine second moment of area \cite{bendtestdiag}.} 
    \label{fig:bendtest}
\end{figure}


\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}


I have tried using \caption[Caption]{my actual caption text}, but my captions in the list of figures shows:
List of Figures

Caption..........................1

and not my caption text.
Any help would be really appreciated! I've been losing my mind over this for days now.


\caption[Three-point bend test to determine second moment of area]{Three-point bend test to determine second moment of area \cite{bendtestdiag}.}

Oh I see!! Thank you so much!
